# Remove ionic 2 ion-card div using Javascript in controller

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I need to remove an ionic 2 card when someone clicks on the trash icon. The code I have so far gives a `querySelector is null` error when I run it.

The view html looks like this:

```html
  <ion-card *ngFor="#mediaItem of mediaItems" id="item{{mediaItem.id}}" class="media-item">


    <ion-card-header class="title-header">
      <div class="title-item">
        {{mediaItem.title}}
      </div>
      <ion-icon name="trash" class="bookmark_trash_icon" (click)="removeItem(mediaItem.id)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-card-header>


    <ion-card-content class="outer-content" >
      
      <img src='{{mediaItem.url}}'>

    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-item class="bookmark-media-item">
      <!-- <button (click)="topup(mediaItem)" clear item-left> -->

      <div style="float:left;">
        <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
        {{mediaItem.liked}} &nbsp;
        <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
        {{mediaItem.disliked}} &nbsp;
      </div>
      <a (click)="showUserProfile(mediaItem.owner, mediaItem.username)" style="float:left;">
        {{mediaItem.username}}
      </a>
      <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="img/tiny-v.png" class="bookmark-v-icon">
        {{mediaItem.credits_left}}
      </div>

    </ion-item>
  
  </ion-card>
```

My controller javascript code looks like this:

```js
 removeItem(theItemID) {
    let cardToHide = '#item'+theItemID;
    document.querySelector(cardToHide).style.display = 'none';
  }
```

The error I get is

```
querySelector is null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the object instead of the id by changing that part of the code:

```
(click)="removeItem(mediaItem)"
```

And then find that object in you `mediaItems` array and delete it from there. Then your view will be automatically updated.

First get the `index` of that object in the array, and then you can use the `mediaItems.splice(index, 1)` to delete it from the array:

```
removeItem(theItem) {
    let index = this.mediaItems.indexOf(theItem);
    this.mediaItems.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: I should have thought of that! Thanks.

Comment: Very good, my friend, I spent the whole afternoon trying to remove an item from my object.